# Get a variable from another document

Tags: php, sql

I am new to PHP. I'd like to get a variable that is in another document in order to insert a value into a table. So, I have this code:
insert.php:

```
$inputField = $_POST['inputField'];
$inputField2 = $_POST['inputField2'];
    $Allowed_traffic = $_POST['Allowed_traffic'];
    $Frequency = $_POST['Frequency'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO users_fup (fup_id, user_id, ModemSn, start_date, end_date, allowed_traffic, realized_traffic, frequency, nextreset, whichdb) VALUES ('NULL','','', '".$inputField."', '".$inputField2."', '".$Allowed_traffic."', '', '".$Frequency."', '', '')";
```

I want to take ModemSn from another file which contains:

```
    $ffup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_fup WHERE ModemSn = '".$row['ModemSn']."' AND start_date <  '$oraoggi' AND end_date > '$oraoggi' ");  
    .
    .
    echo "<td>".$row['ModemSn']."</td><td>".$percent_traffic."</td><td>linksetfup</td><td></td></tr>";
```

The files are not in the same folder.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: what do you mean "file"? You're just selecting from a database, i don't get it

Comment: yes, I know it is vulnerable, but it is on intranet, only employees from the company can connect to the page, so I think that it should not be that secure. I just posted some code from that file...

Comment: Where is `$row['ModemSN']` coming from? I think it's the result of a sql-query, but then again why re-store a something already in your database?

Comment: yea. I think you're right. I should get it from the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly.

What you probably want to do is put the value from `$row['ModemSn']` in an hidden input field in the form that you are using in the above code.

Then you can get the values you want by running the query in the second code block with the `$_POST['ModemSn']` value (from your hidden input field)

Also, how you are building your queries is very vulnerable for SQL Injection (that is what @Quentin means)

Comment: You should ''never'' store a database value in a hidden input field, ever! Once you sent data to the user's machine you cannot trust the value sent back (it might have been changed)... so you need to check the value again, as such you have to query the database again. Result: You can just query the database on submit of the form (not storing anything on the users machine).